# How to write words and their vectors in a CSV file?

Tags: python, csv

Here is how I want my CSV output:

```
word  \t vector
code  \t  0.85
```

Here is what I did:

```
for word in total_words[0]:
    with open("test.csv", "w") as csv_file:   
        writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter='\t')
        writer.writerow(['word', 'vectors'])
        writer.writerow([word, bert(word)])
```

This only gave me the first word and its vector, and not every word I need, and no tabulation for either. Any help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [write header rows to csv python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47589327/write-header-rows-to-csv-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are taking just the first word of total_words for the for loop.

try this:

```
with open("test.csv", "w") as csv_file:   
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter='\t')
    writer.writerow(['word', 'vectors'])
    for word in total_words:
        writer.writerow([word, bert(word)])
```